# Requesting with TOR Browser on Windows platform

Tags: python, selenium, browser, request, tor

There are a little informatin on the web, and most of them are out of date
Is there any body know, how can we do request with Tor browser on windows platform or selenium with TOR? all other answers from stackowerflow are not working..it is time to update answer Regards..

Answer (score 1):

A working example with Selenium and Tor on windows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(r"..\..\..\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile(r"..\..\..\TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, binary)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: gives an error in "tor launcher " window, which gives "tor failed to start".  note : manually tor can start without any problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python tryout this example

Comment: this is not working