# Firefox GeckoDriver not accepting HTTP Proxy IP with user authentication

Tags: python, selenium, http-proxy, geckodriver, firefox-profile

So I have the code below, it is still showing the real IP. No error produced either. Sorry can't share real proxy details :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
PROXY_HOST = "206.41.127.230"

PROXY_PORT = "603230"

USERNAME = "xxx"

PASSWORD = "xx"

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", PROXY_PORT)

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_username", USERNAME)

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_password", PASSWORD)

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your PROXY_PORT is a string. Shouldn't it be an integer? And do you really have six digits in the port number?

Comment: it is Python. Yes , a six digit port

Answer (score 2):

Seems you were close. You need to invoke `update_preferences()` for the *FirefoxProfile* instance **`profile`** and you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = "206.41.127.230"
PROXY_PORT = "6032"
USERNAME = "xxx"
PASSWORD = "xx"

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", PROXY_PORT)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_username", USERNAME)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_password", PASSWORD)
profile.update_preferences()
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/geckodriver', firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
driver.quit()
```

---

### References

You can find a relevant discussions in:

- [How to connect to Tor browser using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python/53942783#53942783)
- [AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'update' error usingFirefoxProfile through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087324/attributeerror-firefoxprofile-object-has-no-attribute-update-error-usingfir/59088827#59088827)

Comment: Not working for me...I do not know why. It is still returning Real IP address.

Comment: When I use proxies via `requests` I used the PROXY URL as `proxy_url = 'https://u:password@' + random_proxy.rstrip('\n')` - HTTPS