# AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'update' error usingFirefoxProfile through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, firefox-profile

Hello Guys I'm having problem on my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy_type',1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http',"91.xx.xxx.xx")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port',xxxx)
# profile.update_preference()  ---> this code letter giving the error.
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('http://whatismyipaddress.com')
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

Here Is The Error I'm Getting:

```
AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I cant figure out the problem i just want to save the profile settings to use.

Comment: `update_preferences()`, with `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think You Need To Change This

```
profile.update_preference()
```

With This:

```
profile.update_preferences()
```

Answer (score 1):

### update_preferences()

[update_preferences()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile.update_preferences) updates the `default_preferences` with the **frozen** preferences of the desired *FirefoxProfile* which is defined as:

```
def update_preferences(self):
    for key, value in FirefoxProfile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen'].items():
        self.default_preferences[key] = value
    self._write_user_prefs(self.default_preferences)
```

---

However, you were close. You need to replace `update_preference()` with **`update_preferences()`** i.e. effectively in your code you need to replace:

```
profile.update_preference()
```

with

```
profile.update_preferences()
```

---

### References

You can find a relevant discussions in:

- [How to connect to Tor browser using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python/53942783#53942783)