# selenium with geckodriver does not respect download dir and download filename when executing window.print();

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have a set up where I print the page as pdf using selenium+gecko. But, whatever I do, it does not seem to respect the `download.dir` option I set nor the download filename.

Here are my settings:

```
        self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        self.headers = {'User-Agent' : uagent, \
                        'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', \
                        'Accept-Language' : 'en-gb,en;q=0.5', \
                        'Accept-Charset' : 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7', \
                        'Keep-Alive' : '115', \
                        'Connection' : 'keep-alive', \
                        'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0'}
        self.profile.set_preference('browser.link.open_newwindow', 1)
        self.profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", uagent)

        self.profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        self.profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/home/foo/')

        self.profile.set_preference("print_printer", "Mozilla Save to PDF")
        self.profile.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
        self.profile.set_preference("print.show_print_progress", False)
        self.profile.set_preference('print.save_as_pdf.links.enabled', True)
        self.profile.set_preference("print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)
        self.profile.set_preference("print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_filename", "file.pdf")
        self.binary = FirefoxBinary('/path/to/Downloads/dir/firefox/firefox')
```

I have also tried:

```
        self.profile.set_preference("print.print_to_filename", "file.pdf")
```

To print I do:

```
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=self.profile, \
                    firefox_binary=self.binary, executable_path='/some/path/dir/and/orm/driver/geckodriver')
        browser.execute_script("window.print();")
```

When I execute this I get the PDF in the directory I execute the script from and always as `mozilla.pdf` I am not sure what settings to use to change this.

I tried changing the page name to see if this will have any effect, but still, it prints out as `mozilla.pdf`

So yea, I am looking for a solution which can:

1. set the directory of the pdf
2. set the name of the pdf

:(

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Once you have configured all the settings through `set_preference()`, finally you have to use ***`update_preferences()`*** as follows:

```
self.profile.update_preferences()
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Python-AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'update' error usingFirefoxProfile through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59088827/7429447)

Comment: lol no this does nothing. I have never used this befoe tbh.. I set all networks via these preferences and have never updated like you have shown.

Comment: this does not do anything really.. atleast in my case..

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, you need to include the path & filename as one.

- Below is using `options`, your example is using `self`, but the idea is the same!

> important to note that printing will rasterize the PDF as an image, you cannot then highlight text...

```py
url = '<__some_public_pdf_URL_here__>'

out_dir = './data/' # whatever your outdir is for the printed file
out_filename = 'file.pdf'
out_path = out_dir + out_filename

options = FirefoxOptions()

options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
options.set_preference("print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)
# this line should guarantee export to correct dir & filename
options.set_preference('print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_filename', '{}'.format(out_path))

options.set_preference("print_printer", "Mozilla Save to PDF")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

   try:
        driver.get(url)
        sleep(3) # give the browser a chance to load PDF
        driver.execute_script('window.print();')
        sleep(10) # give the PDF a chance to print, 10 seconds should be enough
        driver.close()
   except:
        print('oops! failed for {}'.format(url)
```