# "SocketError: [Errno 61] Connection refused" Selenium with TOR

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, tor, firefox-profile

So I was using TOR to act as a way of changing my proxies and ip addresses for my webdriver. Here is the code. All dependencies are installed (including Geckodriver and latest version of Firefox).

```py
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def switchIP():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate()
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)


def my_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.update_preferences()
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    return webdriver.Firefox(options=options, firefox_profile=fp)

for x in range(10):
    proxy = my_proxy("127.0.0.1", 9050)
    proxy.get("https://whatsmyip.com/")
    html = proxy.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    print(soup.find("span", {"id": "ipv4"}))
    print(soup.find("span", {"id": "ipv6"}))
    switchIP()
```

Thanks for the help,
Aarav.

Comment: Where is the connection refused error showing up or what is the stack trace? Can you confirm that Tor's SOCKS proxy is listening on port 9050 and that the controller is listening on port 9051?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
SocketError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

...implies that the connection was refused by the server.

---

This error can surface due to several reasons as follows:

1. Firewall blocking the request/respose.
2. Improper Proxy configurations.
3. Invalid Proxy type.
4. Invalid Proxy host.
5. Invalid Proxy port. etc

---

### This usecase

However I don't see any issues with your code block as such but while using [tor](/questions/tagged/tor) to be able to change the proxies and ip addresses you need to start the **torexe** application using the `popen()` command as follows (example for [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) OS):

```
import os

torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\user_name\path\to\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
```

---

### References

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [How to connect to Tor browser using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python/53942783#53942783)

Comment: I can't run .exe files because im on MAC os . Is there another way to do the above

Comment: @AaravM4 Seems [popen()](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/popen.3.html) does exists for MAC OSX. Try with the absolute path of e.g. `/path/to/tor`