# Port 9050 is not listening

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, tor

I want to use a tbselenium package for browser automation but however when I try to run the code I get the following error TBDriverPortError: SOCKS port 9050 is not listening.

following is the code snippet that I have used.

```
import unittest
from time import sleep
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
import tbselenium.common as cm


class TestSite(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Point the path to the tor-browser_en-US directory in your system
        tbpath = r'C:\Users\Sachin\Desktop\Tor Browsernew'
        self.driver = TorBrowserDriver(tbpath, tbb_logfile_path='test.log')
        self.url = "https://check.torproject.org"

    def tearDown(self):
        # We want the browser to close at the end of each test.
        self.driver.close()

    def test_available(self):
        self.driver.load_url(self.url)
        # Find the element for success
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('on')
        self.assertEqual(str.strip(element.text),
                         "Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.")
        sleep(2)  # So that we can see the page


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

can any one help me solve this error have been struggling for days

Comment: hi sachin ,port 9050 is Versiera Agent Listener i found on google .  Did you try using any other port and find the same issue?

Comment: Hi @RaHuL actually I need to specifically use tor browser and it only uses port 9050 so on other ports the browser is opening but not responding

Comment: Try turn off the firewall and try the same . Sometimes firewall blocks the port . Thanks

Comment: Still the same thing @RaHuL

Comment: @sachinsafale Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python/53942783#53942783) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python/53942783#53942783) discussion helps you?

Comment: @DebanjanB that is something works comfortably fine but I want to use the tbselenium driver any help on this

Comment: @sachinsafale Can you point me to any documentation of **tbselenium**?

Comment: @DebanjanB these might help https://pypi.org/project/tbselenium and https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium/tree/master/tbselenium

Comment: @DebanjanB any help you can provide me

Comment: Tor Browser uses port 9150, try that or look at `netstat -anop` to see what's listening on what ports.

Comment: @DebanjanB anything you found on this

Comment: @sachinsafale Apologies, I din't further investigate this issue involving tor.

Comment: @DebanjanB can you please help ia m really stuck at this

Comment: @sachinsafale Let me see if I can pull out something this weekend then I will publish an answer

Comment: @DebanjanB hi did you pull out something

Comment: @sachinsafale In mid of my R&D. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: @DebanjanB No Problem

Comment: You need to uncomment **ControlPort**, **HashedControlPassword** and **CookieAuthentication** from **Torrc** file.

Comment: @Sangram my torrc does not have any of these

Comment: your  torrc file must be content like this https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/master/src/config/torrc.sample.in or you can manually paste this. which OS you used?

Comment: I use windows 10

Comment: @sangram now the tor doe get connected but however, it closes giving the following error ###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv

Comment: show me the full trackback

Comment: I think that is gecodriver issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206409/discussion-between-sachin-safale-and-sangram).

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment **ControlPort**, **HashedControlPassword** and **CookieAuthentication** from **Torrc** file.

you can get torrc from [here](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/master/src/config/torrc.sample.in)

then reload tor services.

if you are facing issues post full trackback in  your Question

Comment: I am able to connect to tor using ypu method but one issue still persists that i wanted to use the firfox application fromt he tor bundle but this is using normal firfox and due to which i am not able to use the us exit node Though i have mentioned the exit node in torrc

Comment: your solution worked like charm but any help on the country exit nodes

Comment: you can specify exit node from here https://b3rn3d.herokuapp.com/blog/2014/03/05/tor-country-codes

Comment: if you get the solution please click on right tick and up vote for others take help from this question