# 2020 - Windows 10 - Python Selenium with Tor (ERROR: Tor failed to start.)

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I need your help
I'm using Windows 10

It's been 2 years since now that I have put the tor to work on windows and I never got it. this was the code version closest to the solution I have found to date. I have read hundreds of articles on the Internet but I cannot understand the solutions or they are false solutions. If anyone really has the skills to solve this problem and help me, I am very grateful to the stackoverflow.

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(r"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\PROGRAMAS\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile(r"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\PROGRAMAS\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, binary)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Its a duplicate question this is already answered. Please take a look on the below URL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62666075/how-to-initiate-a-tor-browser-9-5-which-uses-the-default-firefox-to-68-9-0esr-us

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Tor with Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696032/accessing-tor-with-selenium-in-python)