# How to open the site https://gem.gov.in/ with Python Selenium using undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I need to open this website https://gem.gov.in/ with Python Selenium

I have tried to do it this way:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
driver.get('https://gem.gov.in/view_contracts')
time.sleep(5)
```

But the site does not load at all. No errors. Just doesn't load

I also tried to use VPN. I use ExpressVPN. Choose India. But still no result

**Question**

How can I open this website?

Comment: `org.gem.gov.in` currently reports they are down for maintenance.

Comment: The client from India says it works fine for him

Answer (score 0):

Using [undetected_chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65534593/7429447) it is still possible to access the [site](https://gem.gov.in/view_contracts).

- Code Block:

  ```
  import undetected_chromedriver as uc

  driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe', use_subprocess=True)
  driver.maximize_window()
  driver.get('https://gem.gov.in/view_contracts')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Advanced search for Contracts and Bid/RA']")))
  driver.save_screenshot("Advanced search for Contracts and Bid.png")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Advanced search for Contracts and Bid]

Comment: I have tried it with undetected_chromedriver and it doesn't work for me. What is your location? Or what VPN do you use?

Comment: I am based at APAC region and haven't used a VPN for this solution.

Comment: Can you please tell what country are you from? I have tried 5 countries from APAC region via VPN + undetected_chromedriver and it still doesn't open

Comment: I'm from India. As an alternative try to use [_**tor**_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53703144/7429447) browser.

Comment: For India it works fine ) The problem is to connect from another country )

Comment: How can I use tor? Never worked with it

Comment: @TiBrains _For India it works fine_: Glad to be able to help you.